# get latest version of all articles with pagination

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

i would like to get the latest version of all journal articles.
I have a strong requirement on performances issue.

I came up with a very fast query:

```
SELECT 
  articleId,
  MAX(version) as currentVersion
FROM mf3_liferay.journalarticle 
GROUP BY articleId 
HAVING currentVersion;
```

I tough about dynamic queries:

```
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(JournalArticle.class);
dynamicQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("status", 0))
        .addOrder(OrderFactoryUtil.desc("version"))
        .setLimit(cur, cur + resultsByPage);
dynamicQuery.setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.groupProperty("version"));
```

I cannot find a way to add the Having clause.

I read about that:
http://www.liferay.com/fr/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/developing-custom-sql-queries-liferay-portal-6-1-dev-guide-en

But I cannot get it to work and I'm worried about performances...

Comment: Could you please specify which database you are using?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Getting any exceptions or not getting the output as desired? What? Custom SQL is the way to go if the SQL query needs to be executed. Thanks

Comment: I am using Mysql 5.6

Comment: @PrakashK: I have no exceptions, just cannot figure out how to get the latest version of all articles with pagination without fetching all the database all the time as I've seen on the net

Comment: Your custom-sql is ok. And you can include pagination in it to not fetch all the records. Also you can fetch the Journal-article instance instead of just two fields. I think you should take a look at web-content-list portlet (since you are using Liferay 6.1) which does what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the Search engine instead of querying the database directly.
It offers better performance, and offers pagination.
Getting the latest versions (the 'current') can be done using a field filter on the field 'head', like this:

```
searchQuery.addRequiredTerm("head", Boolean.TRUE);
```